# The Struts dispatcher cannot be found while deploy

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2, weblogic

When I try to run my Spring + Struts 2 project on WL Server 9.2 (I have to user this version, so please don't ask me to user the newer version of WL Server), I had this error.

The URL address in the browser is :

```
http://localhost:7003/SpringStrust2/
```

Full stacktrace:

```
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
at jsp_servlet.__user._jsp__tag0(__user.java:115)
at jsp_servlet.__user._jspService(User.jsp:12)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3269)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2019)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1925)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1394)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>User.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enble.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="myapp" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="user" class="user">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/User.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

user.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spring + Struts2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <s:form action="user" method="addUser">
        <s:textfield name="username" key="user.name" />
        <s:submit key="submit" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm very sure about putting files in correct folders, including jar libraries in lib folder...

Here is the list of jars I'm using:

```
antlr-runtime-3.0.jar 
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.13.jar 
junit-3.8.1.jar 
ornl-2.6.11.jar 
org.springframework.asm-3.9.9.M3.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.0.M3.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.0.M3.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar 
struts2-core-2.1.6.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar
xwork-2.1.2.jar
```

Comment: Do you think you have enough information you have posted here? And your Struts version is outdated, you should upgrade to the latest version ASAP if you want to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting the `User.jsp` file (with its S2 tags) without running through an action like the error says.

You can either:

- Redirect to a Struts action from the welcome file (a common technique, and trivial)
- configure the container to allow actions as welcome files
- Remove the S2 tags from the welcome file

Comment: OK, I did comment the welcome-file-list part in web.xml file. When I try to deploy it, an error appeared: "<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/FileManagerProvider" Could you show me how to solve it ? Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a dependency. This is a new error, and a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My Struts 2 application was running on localhost like knife on butter but on VPS it failed. Finally the solution is that Web-Inf folder in project conflicts with web-inf folder of Tomcat.

**So move your project/web-inf/web.xml contents to
usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/conf (for Cent OS)**

**and move your jars from youtproject/web-inf/lib to 
usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/lib (for Cent OS)**

For other OS do the same at respective path..

Hope this will be helpful..